# Adding a text input to a gallery item

Tags: office365, powerapps

I created a Power-App in office 365 that allows the users to search for a user from the azure AD and display some info like name, title, direct manager, email etc. After they selected all the people they want there is a button to send it by email to a specific address.

I also wanted to show the employee number, which is a custom attribute synced from our on-premise AD, but as far as I know, PowerApps does not support custom attributes just yet so I had to add a a new field with a text input so that the user could manually input the employee number for each user they select.

The issue is the email received contains the same number for all the people in the list. Actually, it grabs the number from the text input of the last user in the list and use only that for all the selected users.

This is the code on the "submit" button:

```
If(
!IsBlank(PeopleAddedGallery1),
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
    "XXX@YYYY.com",
    "Employee Termination Form",
    "Hello:" & "<br>" & "<br>" & User().FullName & " is requesting the following employees to be terminated:" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & Concat(
        MyPeople,
        "Name: " & DisplayName & "<br>" & "Title: " & JobTitle & "<br>" & "Employee Number: " & EmployeeNumber_input.Text & "<br>" & "Email Adress: " & Mail & "<br>" & "<br>"
    )
));RemoveIf(
MyPeople,
DisplayName in MyPeople.DisplayName)
```

The text input causing the issue is "EmployeeNumber_input.Text".
The other attributes are changing for each user in the list. Only the number is the same (the last one in the list) for all of them.

sample mail output:

```
Hello:
XXXX is requesting the following employees to be terminated:


Name: name1
Title: title1
Employee Number: 567
Email Address: name1@YYYY.com

Name: name2
Title: title12
Employee Number: 567
Email Address: name2@YYYY.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a new column for the employee number text field to the MyPeople table.
The concat function will loop for your MyPeople table and will ready the last employee number on the form .
by adding the new column to the list of the employee's table it will be read for each employee record.

Comment: How do I do that? as far as I know I would need to create a 2nd collection that will grab the info from the 1st collection plus the info from the text input. Any simpler way?